# How can I apply an Angularjs Directive only if a particular filter is applied?

Tags: angularjs

I am retro-fitting angular into an existing project where the date output is in an undesired format. (2013/01/01)

I would like to use the AngularJs date filter to format the dates. Unfortunately the current date strings are not is a standard ISO format and I cannot change them.

So I figured, the best way would be to apply a new filter before the standard date one, to parse the date.

`ng-bind="prop.ApplicationDate | DateParse | date:fullDate"`

```
angular.module('rjDateParse', [])
.filter('DateParse', function() {
    return function(date) {
        var parsedDate;
        try {
            parsedDate = Date.parse(date);
        } catch (err){
            parsedDate = date;
        }
        return parsedDate;
    }
})
```

This works fine.

**Except I am aware of the issues I will have with certain dates in this format. 2013/12/01 for instance, could come back with two completely different dates.**

So I wanted to create a directive that allowed the date to be clicked to toggle between the original and the parsed date.

**My problem:** How to apply this directive ONLY if the filter has been used. I don't want to have to add a class or attribute to the element manually to trigger this.

```
angular.module('rjDateParse', [])
.filter('DateParse', function() {
    return function(date) {
        var parsedDate;
        try {
            parsedDate = Date.parse(date);
        } catch (err){
            parsedDate = date;
        }
        return parsedDate;
    }
})
.directive('DateParse', function() {
    return {
        //apply this only if dateparse filer is applied
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Rob

p.s. I don't have any controllers currently - I am trying to keep it that way :)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but why not create your own filter doing it properly right away? What do you mean that a date could come back with two entirely different dates?

Comment: @SveinT in the UK the date format 2013/12/01 would be 1st Dec, in the US it might mean 12th Jan. The filter isn't the problem as such, it's the directive. I want it to run only if the filter is used.

Comment: I suspected you meant that, but you actually have inconsistant date formats from the backend? And how would showing the original date solve that? Even a human wouldn't tell the one from the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can change format of angular "date" filter in simple way:

```
{{prop.dateToFormat | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

This code formats date to standard ISO-format

Comment: Hi Alex - thanks, But i don't think that's right. That's the output format. Angular expects a dateObject, number or string in ISO format as the input - I don't have that.